# How to subtract a vector from each row of a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector

**Solved, solution in comments, thank you.**

A 14x14 matrix named "RET", a 1x14 vector named "R". How do I make a new matrix "Si" such that each row of "Si" is each row of "Ret" subtracted by "R"?
I've tried

```
Si=Ret-R
```

And

```
Si=Do[Ret[[i]]-R,{i,14}]
```

Neither worked.

Comment: You noticed that your first try subtracted R from all the columns? So you accomplish the same with rows by transposing: Si=Transpose[Transpose[Ret] - R]

Comment: `Si = # - R & /@ Ret`

Comment: Replacing `Do` with `Table` should also work...

Comment: Or `Si = Ret - ConstantArray[R,Length[Ret]]`...